Access certain tabs in Excel using password
We have VBA code requiring users to enter a password to access a particular tab.
We need to adjust the code so the user can access two tabs.
For example I'd like the user for East to access both the tab 'East' and the tab 'East_Dashboard'.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim pword As String
    On Error GoTo endit
    pword = InputBox("Enter Your Password")
    Select Case pword
      Case Is = "EastPassword": Sheets("East").Visible = True
      Case Is = "NorthPassword": Sheets("North").Visible = True
      Case Is = "WestPassword": Sheets("West").Visible = True
      Case Is = "MasterPassword": Call UnHideAllSheets
    End Select
    Sheets("Welcome").Visible = False
    Exit Sub
endit:
    MsgBox "Incorrect Password - contact Name"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Welcome").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sht.Name <> "Welcome" Then
            sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Your MsgBox "Incorrect Password - contact Name" should be in a Case Else inside Select Case   There's no run-time error if Select Case doesn't make a match.  Note also that Sheets("Welcome").Visible = False will always run, regardless of whether the user enters a correct password.

You can adjust the code in one of the case blocks. This will convert that block from a single line, to multiple line.
  Select Case pword
  Case Is = "EastPassword" 
      Sheets("East").Visible = True
      Sheets("East_Dashboard").Visible = True
  Case Is = "NorthPassword": Sheets("North").Visible = True
  Case Is = "WestPassword": Sheets("West").Visible = True
  Case Is = "MasterPassword": Call UnHideAllSheets
  End Select


Change the text of the Select Case statement to this:
Select Case pword
  Case "EastPassword"
      Sheets("East").Visible = True
      Sheets("East_Dashboard").Visible = True
  Case "NorthPassword"
      Sheets("North").Visible = True
      Sheets("North_Dashboard").Visible = True
  Case "WestPassword"
      Sheets("West").Visible = True
      Sheets("West_Dashboard").Visible = True
  Case "MasterPassword": Call UnHideAllSheets
  Case Else
      MsgBox "Incorrect Password - contact Name"     
End Select

